# A better approach to creating a JSON string in GWT?

Tags: java, json, gwt, generics

I have a variable arguments defined as Object[][] enable my app to send a series of KEY/VALUE pairs to a function. Below the code handles Strings, Integers and ArrayLists of Strings and Integers. I'd like to extend this to support Doubles and Booleans (and ArrayLists of both).

The function has a lot of repetitive code.

Update: I am using the GWT framework.

Q1. Is this the right approach but in need of a generic class provide easier maintenance? If so how?
Q2. Is there a better alternative approach?

```
final static int KEY = 0;
final static int VALUE = 1;
...
String buildParamaters(Object[][] arguments) {
    JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();
    for (Object[] arg : arguments) {
        if (isType(arg[VALUE], "java.util.ArrayList")) {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            if (isType(arg[VALUE], "java.lang.Integer")) {
                ArrayList<String> values = (ArrayList<String>) arg[VALUE];
                for (int i=0; i<values.size(); i++) {
                    array.set(i, new JSONString(values.get(i)));
                }
            } else {
                ArrayList<Integer> values = (ArrayList<Integer>) arg[VALUE];
                for (int i=0; i<values.size(); i++) {
                    array.set(i, new JSONNumber(values.get(i)));
                }
            }
            parameters.put(arg[KEY].toString(), array);
        } else if (isType(arg[VALUE], "java.lang.Integer")) {
            parameters.put(arg[KEY].toString(), new JSONNumber(((Integer)arg[VALUE]).doubleValue()));
        } else {
            parameters.put(arg[KEY].toString(), new JSONString((String)arg[VALUE]));
        }
    }
    return parameters.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a framework like Jackson, which is able to map any Java object to JSON and vice versa:

```
public class User {

    private int age = 29;
    private String name = "mkyong";
    private List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
            add("msg 1");
            add("msg 2");
            add("msg 3");
        }
    };

    //getter and setter methods

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [age=" + age + ", name=" + name + ", " +
                "messages=" + messages + "]";
    }
}

//1. Convert Java object to JSON format
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), user);
```

or

```
//2. Convert JSON to Java object
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), User.class);
```

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

(Btw: you need to add getters and setters to User)

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. I like the type-checking it offers but the approach doesn't actually cut down on repetitive code but instead will have many classes that look very similar. The toString method will also have to be edited each time a field is added to the class.

Comment: if the OP's json string is not defined ahead of time (e.g., say, it is based on some user input - specifically, the keys are based on user input), then jackson will have a hard(er) time converting, because you don't have an existing bean class to convert to, and end up with what essentially is Map. If this is the case, might as well use a real map via gwt javascript object overlay.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Answer (score 0):

You could construct your own classes to prevent this unsafe mess. Or you could use an framework (GSON works good on Android, Jackson has it's problems but works fine for JavaSE) but if you want it faster and a little bit smaller (e.g. for android dev.) you could do this:

Introduce an interface:

```
public interface JSONRepresentable {
   public JSONValue getJsonValue();
}
```

With this you could introduce list classes like this:

```
public class IntList extends ArrayList<Integer> implements JSONRepresentable {
   @Override
   public JSONValue getJsonValue() {
       JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
       int size = this.size();

       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
          arr.set(i, new JSONNumber(get(i)));
       }

       return arr;
   }
}
```

The downer with this decorator pattern is the usage of Strings. You can't inherent from string so you would to have write a replacement like this:

```
StringValue implements JSONRepresentable {
   private String val;

   public StringValue(String val) { this.val = val; }
   public StringValue() { this(""); }

   public String value() { return val; }
   public void setValue(String val) { this.val = val; }

   @Override
   public JSONValue getJsonValue() {
       return new JSONString(val);
   }
}
```

And then implement your own JSONRepresentable for ArrayList like above.

You could then replace your Object[][] with a Map[String, JSONRepresentable]. Maybe that's not perfect for you, but it could give you pointer on how to solve that without going down the reflection route.

That would be pretty fast in comparison to the reflection based frameworks like GSON or Jackson. But that does only work if you using a JSON framework which has such a class hierarchy.

What do you use?

Comment: could you expand on your example code? I fully take your "unsafe mess" point!

Comment: @Carl I added a little bit of code. It isn't a perfect solution yet but maybe it helps you find one.

Comment: thanks @schlingel. this gives food for thought. I'll investigate further.

Comment: having to declare new StringValue("..") for parameters does feel rather the wrong direction. Perhaps there's an approach that can use Strings directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for your converting Java object to JSON array or vice-versa. This 3rd party tool is developed by Google team itself. Its pretty easy and safe to use it. Another similar 3rd party library for GWT is [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)